# Protect wood furniture legs from damage

Tags: physical-protection

I have wooden furniture (bed and more) with feet which look like this:

[image]

There are thin weak parts which get chipped away easily.

I have a vacuum cleaner like this one:

[image]

Which is old and with questionable navigation algorithms (it's 6 years old after all) which tends to scratch the furniture when it circles around it.

I'm going to put teflon tape the sides of the vacuum to make it smoother (after 6 years the plastic is scratched and rough), but I doubt it will be enough.
See the tape:

[image]

How can I protect the wood to last longer and avoid chipping/scratching?

I thought about using office transparent tape, however I know from past experience that the glue will dry up in few years and the residues will be difficult to remove.

Which kind of transparent product can I use, in addition to the teflon tape on the vacuum, to protect the furniture?

The answer (or the comments) of course may comprise tips for restoring the damages that are already there, but the question is about future protection and not about restoration.

Comment: You might get the protection you want by using self-stick foam or glued on felt weatherstripping applied to the vacuum.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the damage is being done by impact rather than abrasion.

The teflon tape might help, but I don't think it will eliminate future damage. You might get the protection you want by using self-stick foam or glued on felt weatherstripping applied to the vacuum.

Maybe something like this: [Door Weather Stripping](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TXJNG2C) or this: [Heavy-Duty Self Adhesive Weatherstrip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0025KUSY6)

Wood stain [touch-up markers/crayons like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R5F37FG) may help hide the damage.

Comment: This. Pad the vacuum. So not a woodworking Q really.

Comment: Nope. In this case the "wood" is insignificant.